# PHP is_file and server root relative paths

Tags: php, file, path, root

How can I use is_file with a path like: /folder/file.jpg please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the path starts with a / this means the path is absolute. When the path is relative (ie not starting with /) then the path relative to the php script is taken. If you want to have /folder/file.jpg relative to the server root, you can append the root.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/file.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
$is_file = is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/file.jpg');
```