# Server root/file structure in PHP

Tags: php, root, server, slash, easyphp

I'm doing a small intranet site for my employer. I'm the only developer on it at this point. (Woe be unto them.) I'm still very much a noob to web development.

I'm running the dev version of this site with NetBeans as the "server" (ultimately using EasyPHP). When I run the project in NetBeans, the browser has the site root as "localhost:8000" or whatever port. Nothing wrong there. When I try to run it directly thru EasyPHP, It has "aliases" which point to specified directories on my hard drive as the site roots, so the browser says something like "127.0.0.1/Intranet/" as the site root. Unfortunately, that breaks everything in multiple ways. For one, the way I was getting the site's root:

```
 define('WEB_ROOT', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT');
 define('SOURCE_ROOT', dirname(WEB_ROOT);
```

`WEB_ROOT` ended up pointing to the directory EasyPHP is installed, rather than the directory the site is in, so naturally any includes with `WEB_ROOT` in them broke. Instead, there was another $_SERVER key called `'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'` that points to the right place. OK, easy enough to test if that key `isset()` and use it if it is, but then, the links to my css and javascript files were broken, because they were linked in my code like `/js.js` with a leading slash. I thought the leading `/` would automatically point to the site root, but instead it seems to point to the root in the browser, since the console said it couldn't find "127.0.0.1/js.js" when it should have been looking for "127.0.0.1/Intranet/js.js".

Does any of this make sense? What does the leading slash actually do? Should I link my css and js with my WEB_ROOT constants instead? I don't want to do it with relative paths, because (at this point) there are a lot of directories and subdirectories in this site, any of which need to find WEB_ROOT/js.js or style.css.

Although the prod version is working (it's on a different computer with different server software), these errors make me think I'm doing something wrong. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

PS. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009966/php-is-file-and-server-root-relative-paths)'s answer speaks to my question somewhat, but I'm wondering if anyone can explain the forward slash further.

Comment: In HTML, the leading slash refers to the web root, `127.0.0.1/` in this case. It's not related to PHP or the document root.

Comment: What he said. Make your urls relative, or use base http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/base

Comment: I guess what I'm figuring out is that the leading slash is interpreted _by the browser_ (not the PHP server) to mean the root of whatever URL is in the address bar. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, what you “figured out” is correct – of course, it could not be any other way, because the client doesn’t know _anything_ about your server’s internal file system …

Comment: CBroe, that makes perfect sense. The client is the one that loads those files based on what it finds in the <head> tag, after the PHP has been interpreted and sent to the browser. It's starting to make a bit more sense...